# I am Reading EXE through .net Its working fine on local machine but hangs on IIS server

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

string fileName = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/CPRDetailsText/CPRDetails2017.txt"));

```
        // Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it. 
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }
        string fileLoc = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/CardReader/SDKReadCard.exe"));          
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = fileLoc,
                Arguments = "WScript.Shell",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
        // proc.Close();
        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Close();
```

By using above code I want to fetch the output of the so its working fine on local machine but when I published to the iis server its hang the website and iis server

Comment: Are you sure that argument is correct?

Comment: yes argument is correct

Comment: I'd set a timeout on WaitForExit(...) and see what the output is (standard or error). It will probably tell you a lot about the problem. I'm going to assume that it's likely a permissions issue that isn't being handled in SDKReadCard, and then it's just sitting there.